# Regex for Mobile Number with or without Country Code

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to validate a text field in my registration form for which I want a Regex.

The textbox will accept a mobile number like 9999999999(10 digit - starting with 7 or 8 or 9).
The user may alternatively write +919999999999, where +91 is country code (+91 for India, but can accept any other like +110 or +52), or he may also write 09999999999 (first 0 for own country)

Here, the user have 3 choices,

1. adding the mobile number with country code
2. simply without country code or 0 prefixed
3. With a zero prefixed in mobile number.

Though not required, my page is in asp.net, and I am using built-in regular expression validator.

Comment: Not all mobile numbers start with 7, 8 or 9. Mine starts with 4. Nor are they all 10 digits, mine is 9.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From what I can see, this should work. The prefix is optional and is stored into the first match group, with the main number going into the second group.

```
^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$
```

But if you can give us some test cases for each, it'd help us in giving you a working regex for what you want.

Props to SchlaWiener in the comments for the correct limit on the country code length.

Comment: This will also match `+1234567999999999` ;)

Comment: @SchlaWiener Yes - he didn't specify any kind of limit as to how long the area code can be considered valid, so I just left it as "at least one number following the +". Changing the first section to `^([0|\+[0-9]{123,456})?` and replacing `123` with the minimum length and `456` with the maximum length will fix that

Comment: Ok thanks, @SchlaWiener and Joe again for update on that, Joe was correct, I didn't mentioned the max/min size for that, but I actually required it. So, cheers..

Comment: You're right, he didn't specify a limit. However wikipedia does: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes so it should be `\d{1,5}`

Comment: Regardless of any specific country code, this `^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([0-9]{10})$` will also work for generic phone numbers

Comment: In  `^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$` regex, I don't think `[` is needed before `0` at start

Comment: may not be related to the question, if using bootstrap  can handle this in html without extra code like this <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="123-45-678" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}" required>

Comment: @Naga, it has nothing to do with bootstrap. The `type` and `pattern` are HTML attributes for `<input>` tag and will work regardless.

Comment: @Cyberpks I agree, sorry for my English, what I meant was without any javascript code can use the pattern attribute in HTML5 rather

Answer (score 15):

Simple regexp for Indian mobile number validation: `/^[0]?[6789]\d{9}$/`

Support
08888888888(Zero appending)
7878787878,8634456876,9545559877(any mobile number precede by 7,8,9 and followed by other 9 digits)

Full function

```
function mobileNumber(){

     var Number = document.getElementById('YOUR ELEMENT ID').value;
     var IndNum = /^[0]?[789]\d{9}$/;

     if(IndNum.test(Number)){
        return;
    }

    else{
        $('#errMessage').text('please enter valid mobile number');
        document.getElementById('profile_telephoneNumber').focus();
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `/^[0]?[6789]\d{9}$/ ` since now indian mobile numbers can also start with the digit 6.

Answer (score 4):

Try following:

```
function validateMobile(mobilenumber) {   
    var regmm='^([0|+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$';
    var regmob = new RegExp(regmm);
    if(regmob.test(mobilenumber)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer

Comment: While this code **may** answer the question, it is always good to explain/support it.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
^(\+[\d]{1,5}|0)?[7-9]\d{9}$
```

Comment: for Indian mobile number following regex also works  
`^[6-9]\d{9}$`  
`if (! /^[6-9]\d{9}$/.test(mobile_no)) {  
// Error code here  
}`  
[http://fiddly.org](http://fiddly.org/f8521/1/what-will-be-the-regular-expression-for-indian-mobile.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it using string manipulation. Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/XJ53F/)

```
str = "+919999999999"
cc = str.split(str.slice(-10))[0]
```

The result will be `+91`

Answer (score 2):

**For Mobile Number Validation - Please Use this REGEX**

```
var mobile_number = 9867345673;   // return true
var mobile_number = 1234566667;   // return false
var mob_regex = /^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$/;
if(mob_regex.test(mobile_number)){
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

**See Attached Screenshot for Reference.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById('mobile_number').value != ""){

       var y = document.getElementById('mobile_number').value;
       if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
       {
          alert("Invalid Mobile No.");
          document.getElementById('mobile_number').focus();
          return false;
       }

       if (y.length>10 || y.length<10)
       {
            alert("Mobile No. should be 10 digit");
            document.getElementById('mobile_number').focus();
            return false;
       }
       if (!(y.charAt(0)=="9" || y.charAt(0)=="8"))
       {
            alert("Mobile No. should start with 9 or 8 ");
            document.getElementById('mobile_number').focus();
            return false
       }
 }
```

**and you can also see in more exampled link**
[click here](http://www.giveg.com/itechmentors/content/javascript-email-validation-and-mobile-number-validation)

http://p2p.wrox.com/javascript-how/64920-validation-phone-number-mobile-number.html

Answer (score 0):

for generically checking phone number with its country code
**/^[+][0-9]{1,5}[0-9]{10}$/**
you can use above regex

Answer (score 0):

For any Chilean number use:

```
/^(\+?56)?((9\d{8})|(22\d{7})|(23\d{7})|(43\d{7})|(42\d{7})|(41\d{7})|(45\d{7})|(65\d{7})|(64\d{7})|(67\d{7})|(61\d{7})|(63\d{7}))$/
```

To use only a cellphone validation:

```
/^(\+?56)?(9\d{8})$/
```

You can check more specifications over:

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Prefijos_telef%C3%B3nicos_de_Chile
https://www.entel.cl/ayudalinea/codigos_area_nacional.html