# Country code validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a form validation and I need to validate phone number with or without country code. Example: +1-555-532-3455, 555-555-5555, +919965425422.

Can any one suggest me how to achieve it with regular expression.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338267/validate-phone-number-with-javascript

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've tried, and the expected output(if any). Most users are more than happy to provide code for a coder in distress, but Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Apparently you also want optional separators between parts. Try [*Google*](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=regular+expression+validate+phone+number&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=PeS7V_fJNtLr8AfU3oJw).

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12858073/5292301

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var reg = "(?:\s+|)((0|(?:(\+|)91))(?:\s|-)*(?:(?:\d(?:\s|-)*\d{9})|(?:\d{2}(?:\s|-)*\d{8})|(?:\d{3}(?:\s|-)*\d{7}))|\d{10})(?:\s+|)"; 

    function PhoneValidation(phoneNumber)
    {  
          var OK = reg.match(phoneNumber);  
          if (!OK) {
              window.alert("phone number isn't  valid");  
          }else{  
              window.alert("phone number is  valid");  
          } 
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Shakir Ahamed, but this expression is not working for Indian number +919965436323 919965224232.

Comment: I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'".

Comment: @User123 if this is help full please accept the answer

Comment: I got The solution in some other source @Shakir Ahamed. But still thanks alot for your help.. :) I will accept your answer. :)