# Quasar input give multiple validations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

```
     <q-input
        v-model="userForm.mobile"
        type="text"
        label="Mobile"
        counter
        maxlength="10"
        color="info"
        lazy-rules
        :rules="[
          (val) => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Mobile number is required',
          (val) =>
            (typeof val !== number) ||
            'Mobile number should be valid',
        ]"
      />
```

I'm trying to do 2 validations, but this is not working,
Trying to return an error if is it empty or not a number
Really appreciate it if somebody could help thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your validation flow is fair, but you misspelt the `Number` keyword. It's highly recommended to define your validation methods in the methods section.

I wrote you a simple sample:

```html
<template>
  <q-form @submit="submit">
    <q-input
      counter
      lazy-rules
      type="text"
      label="Mobile"
      maxlength="10"
      color="info"
      mask="##########"
      :rules="[requiredRule, mobileRule]"
      v-model="userForm.mobile"
    />
    <q-btn
      type="submit"
      label="Submit"
    />
  </q-form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BaseInputValidation',
  data() {
    return {
      userForm: {
        mobile: null,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    requiredRule(val) {
      if (!val) {
        return 'Mobile number is required';
      }
      return true;
    },
    mobileRule(val) {
      if (!/^\d{10}$/.test(val)) {
        return 'Mobile number should be valid';
      }
      return true;
    },
    submit() {
      // Do submit
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I separate rules into methods to boost the render speed. You can also merge rule functions or define them in a global file to reuse elsewhere.

I filled the mask prop to limit the input value to a-ten-number-only input.

I used a plain regex to check numbers, it's better to be replaced with [a better one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857979/regex-for-mobile-number-with-or-without-country-code) :-)